# Qt4 QSettings save enumeration value (for example Qt::CheckState)

Tags: qt4, settings, enumeration

i wanna save state of QCheckBok in QSetting, i can cast its value to int but maybe exists more simple and proper method to do it?

here is my code:

```
QSetting setting;
Qt::CheckState checkState;
//...
checkState = (Qt::CheckState)setting.value("checkState", Qt::Unchecked).toUInt();
//...
setting.setValue("checkState", (uint)checkState);
setting.sync();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, try to avoid C-style casts.  For example, replace the following line:

```
checkState = (Qt::CheckState)setting.value("checkState", Qt::Unchecked).toUInt();
```

with this:

```
checkState = static_cast<Qt::CheckState>(setting.value("checkState", Qt::Unchecked).toUint());
```

The line where you cast `checkState` to a `uint` should also be changed.

Secondly, QSettings relies on QVariant for setting and retrieving values.  QVariant can usually be expanded to support additional types using the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro.  Here's the documentation:

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

However, this mechanism does not appear to work properly with enumerations (when you call the `value()` member function on QVariant).  So what you have right now (minus the C-style casting) is fine.