# enum class in QVariant in QSettings

Tags: c++11, qt5, qvariant, qsettings, enum-class

I have a problem with enum classes, QVariants and the QSettings class. There are enum class values that I want to store within a QVariant which goes into a QSettings instance. So, my code actually looks something like this:

```
enum class Foo
{
    Bar1, Bar2
}
Q_ENUMS(Foo)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo)

...

Foo value = Bar2;
QSettings settings;
settings.setValue(QString("Foo"), QVariant::fromValue(value));
```

At this point in executing the code, an assertion jumps in and complains:

```
ASSERT failure in QVariant::save: "Invalid type to save", file kernel\qvariant.cpp
```

Searching the internet, I found out that the class is missing a fitting << and >> operator. But that is not an option for enum classes. I even tried to use

```
qRegisterMetaType<Foo>("Foo");
```

but it did not help. Maybe you have some other suggestions/solutions for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enums, which are masked unsigned ints, seem to be a problem, see

[Qt4 QSettings save enumeration value (for example Qt::CheckState)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102971/qt4-qsettings-save-enumeration-value-for-example-qtcheckstate)

The solution there and probably here would be to convert it an unsigned. To check if the static_cast-result back to the enum is valid you might add `Foo_lowest` and `Foo_highest` values to the beginning and end of the enum range.

Comment: You are right, this is a problem with enums in QVariants. My original implementation was saving the actual (unsigned) integer values in the QVariant. Now I tried the scoped enums, but I ran into this problem with QVariants. However, I switched back to the original implementation with your trick of lowest/highest values in the enum. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Q_ENUM](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_ENUM) since Qt 5.5 and not worry about calling `qRegisterMetaType()`:

```
enum class Foo
{
    Bar1, Bar2
}
Q_ENUM(Foo)

...

Foo value = Foo::Bar2;
QSettings settings;
settings.setValue(QString("Foo"), QVariant::fromValue(value));
```